# SignalR Performance counter not displaying in the performance monitor

Tags: signalr

I installed the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils version 1.1.0.0 and then install the performance counters using signalr.exe ipc.

In the performance monitor under category "signalr" I can see all the performance counters but it says no instances...so if I add one of the counters in the monitor they don't appear.

My signalr server is hosted on IIS as asp.net web api. Both server and client are using same version of signalr i.e. 1.1.0.0.

Any idea?

Comment: Still the same in 2.0.0 rc1, I would love to see these performance counters

Comment: any answer for ASP.NET Core SignalR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue while trying to run the "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.LoadTestHarness" from the SignalR source code. I even went so far as to create a full website in my local IIS 8 on Windows 8 (with a DNS entry in my machine's host file pointing the website address to my loop-back ip address - 127.0.0.1).

What ended up working for me was changing the AppPool's Identity to LocalSystem where the load test harness site was running.

A quick how-to for those not familiar, open up IIS, go to the Application Pools, find the Application Pool that the site in question is running under, right-click>Advanced Settings, find the *Identity* entry, and change it to LocalSystem (from ApplicationPoolIdentity).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

To use these on full IIS you need to add the app pool user for your application to the Performance Monitor Users group.

Comment: I always have the same issue, is there a way to avoid rebooting? GPUpdate.exe I suppose is only about forcing group policy.

Comment: This got me the counters but they were all zero!